# Neo4j Cypher query performance optimization

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Neo4j Cypher query

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE dg.id = 1 
MATCH (childD)-[relationshipValueRel4:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(filterCharacteristic4:Characteristic) 
WHERE filterCharacteristic4.id = 4 
WITH relationshipValueRel4, childD, dg 
WHERE  (ANY (id IN [2,3] 
WHERE id IN relationshipValueRel4.optionIds ))  
WITH childD, dg  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[vg:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE c.id IN [2, 3] 
WITH childD, dg, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
WITH childD , dg , toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInt(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes  
ORDER BY  weight DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10 
WITH * MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[rup:UPDATED_BY]->(up:User)  
RETURN ru, u, rup, up, childD AS decision, weight, totalVotes, 
[ (dg)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD) | {entityId: toInt(entity.id),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, 
[ (dg)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) | {criterionId: toInt(c1.id),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, [ (dg)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[v1:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)  WHERE  NOT ((ch1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-())  | {characteristicId: toInt(ch1.id),  optionIds: v1.optionIds, valueIds: v1.valueIds, value: v1.value, available: v1.available, totalHistoryValues: v1.totalHistoryValues, totalFlags: v1.totalFlags, description: v1.description, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

I'm not sutisfied with the performance of this query execution.

This is PROFILE output:

```
Cypher version: CYPHER 3.3, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 3296130 total db hits in 2936 ms
```

[image]

Is there any chance to optimize this query performance ?

Answer (score 0):

It will be a little hard to optimize this query without a dataset, knowledge of you graph and what you are searching to do.

Performances depend on :

1. Query itself
2. Schema (index & constrainsts)
3. Graph modeling
4. Neo4j configuration
5. Hardware

There is no big problem on your query, even if it can be written into a more readable state for me (ex: one big `match`, sugar syntax on `where` clause in the `match`, replace the `any` by an `or`, ...)  , but it will not change the query plan.

Be sure to use **query parameters** with this query to avoid to recalculate the query plan of this long query everytimes.

Your query pass most of its times into `(childD)-[relationshipValueRel4:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(:Characteristic)` + the `where` clause on it (ie. 1.5M * 2 dbhits). 
So a solution can be **to change the model** by creating some relationships like that : `HAS_VALUE_ON_WITH_OPTID_1`, `HAS_VALUE_ON_WITH_OPTID_2` ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use query parameters. Also, I think the issue is exactly with :HAS_VALUE_ON relationship. One idea is trying to use manual indexes https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_using_manual_index_on_relationship_properties . What do you think - will it help here ?

Comment: could you please describe proposed solution with `HAS_VALUE_ON_WITH_OPTID_1`, `HAS_VALUE_ON_WITH_OPTID_2` with more details?

Comment: Instead of creating a generic relationship type `(:Decision)-[:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(:Characteristic)` with a property `id` on it, you can directly put this property into the type like this : `(:Decision)-[:HAS_VALUE_ON_WITH_ID_X]-(:Characteristic)` where `X` is the value of your property. With that your query will not expand 1.5M rels and make a filter, but just the 75K. A graph can be it's own index ^^