# Neo4j Manual Index on Relationship Properties

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-apoc, spring-data-neo4j-5

I'm going to try in my application [Neo4j Manual Index on Relationship Properties](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_using_manual_index_on_relationship_properties) in order to fix the performance issue I faced [Neo4j Cypher query performance optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748573/neo4j-cypher-query-performance-optimization)

I have a few question which is not clear to me from the official Neo4j documentation:

> ```
> MATCH (:Flight)-[r:DESTINATION]->(:Airport)
> CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r,['taxi_time'])
> RETURN count(*)
> ```
>
> The statement will create the relationship index with the same name as
>   relationship-type, in this case DESTINATION and add the relationship
>   by its properties to the index.

1. When do I need to create this relationship index? It should be done once(let's say at the application startup) or do I need to invoke this APOC function each time new `-[r:DESTINATION]->` relationship is added between `Flight` and `Airport` nodes?
2. In case of existing `-[r:DESTINATION]->` relationship update, how to update this information in the appropriate manual index?
3. In case of deleting some of `Flight` or `Airport` node - do I need to manually find and remove appropriate `-[r:DESTINATION]->` relationships from the manual index or it will be done automatically by APOC and Neo4j?
4. In case of Spring Data Neo4j project - how to properly execute queries that contain APOC functions? For example, I want to call `apoc.index.addRelationship`  in order to create the manual index for the relationship properties. Can I use `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session.query` for this purpose?
5. What the consistency model is used for the manual indexes - Do they use eventual consistency or strong consistency model between the index and the original data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree Neo4J documentation on this issue is really insufficient.

To answer your questions:

1.If you upgraded your Neo4J from an older version that used automatic relationship index you would need to run APOC (only once) to index your existing relationships using something like

`MATCH ()-[r]->() CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r,['property_1','property_2']) RETURN count(*);`

You would then need to set up a trigger to any new relationship you add to that index, running something like this once:

`CALL apoc.trigger.add('RELATIONSHIP_INDEX',"UNWIND {createdRelationships} AS r MATCH ()-[r]->() CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r,['property_1','property_2']) RETURN count(*)", {phase:'after'})`

(you will need to activate `apoc.trigger.enabled=true` in `neo4j.conf` file before)

2.See above

3.You would need to remove them also from the index, it is not done automatically. Set up an APOC trigger with `removeRelationshipByName()` for that.

4.Should be possible.

5.Somebody from Neo4J should answer this.

Hope this helps and saves you some time!

Comment: @alexanoid I was not right about removing the relationships. they don't get automatically removed from the index. i modified my answer above with the correct solution.